# Search bar for searching in article in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, search

Hello there, I'm new iphone developer and I want you guidance…

I want to make an app with legal terms and explanation to different legal articles…
The problem is that I want to have a search bar, so the user is able to search inside the article for any word that he wants…how can this be done???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have array of dictionary and i am searching record like this

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
        ProductFilteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        for (NSMutableDictionary * cty in globleAry)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [[cty objectForKey:@"Name"] rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [ProductFilteredArray addObject:cty];
            }
        }
    
    //copy this array in arrat of table
    tableArray = [ProductFilteredArray mutableCopy];
    [table reloadData];
}
```