# Sort NSArray with NSPredicate then store in a new array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `UITableView` that gets populated via an array (`tableArray`), who gets populated from core data.

each `UITableViewCell` gets assigned a number at creation time and the numbers are stored in an array. (`numberArray`)

when the user reorders the rows, the numbers get moved around in the array (in conjunction with the `tableView` of course)

So two Mutable arrays are used here.

The `numberArray` holds the numbers (or the order) of the `TableViewCells`. 
I need to sort the array that holds the `UITableViewCell`'s text (`tableArray`)
to reflect the same order that the `numberArray` holds.

Also, this is important: as i said before, each cell gets assigned a number, this number is stored in the `numberArray`,

I need both of the arrays to be sorted to hold the same values in the same place.

So for example:

`tableArray` hold some objects:

```
1) hi
2) whats Up
3) this
4) is cool!
```

so as you can see each object here was assigned a number 1-4. 
and each of these numbers is added to the `numberArray`.

The user can move the cells around so obviously the order of the numbers will change.

So when the view loads up, i need to get the exact order of the `numberArray` whether it is

```
1,2,3,4 or 2,4,3,1
```

and i need to sort the `tableArray` to reflect the same order as the `numberArray`
so when the view loads up, if the `numberArray's` order is 2,3,4,1 i want the `tableArray's` order to be set to

2"whats up", 3"this", 4"is cool!", 1"hi".

I believe i can do this via `NSPredicate`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

cellForRow:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString * identifier = @"identifier";

self.myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (self.myCell == nil) {
    self.myCell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

HandgunAmmo *handgunAmmo = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.myCell.brandLabel.text = handgunAmmo.brand;
self.myCell.caliberLabel.text = handgunAmmo.caliber;
self.myCell.numberOfRoundsLabel.text = handgunAmmo.numberOfRounds;
return self.myCell;
}
```

And in my `viewWIllAppear` method:

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

```
if (self.context == nil)
{
    self.context = [(RootAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HandgunAmmo" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *array = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    [self setTableArray:array];

[self.ammoTable reloadData];
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

So, the reason why the array doesnt stay persistent when being changed is because im loading the data from core data, and i call `[self setTableArray:array];` which reloads all of the data from core data into the array, then it populates the tableview with the array. So i need to be able to sort the `array` before i set it equal to `self.tableArray`.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/10/predicates.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114453/search-bar-for-searching-in-article-in-ios/15116710#comment21378814_15116710

Comment: You can't, with normal Objective-C API stuff, sort two arrays with one sort.  You basically need a variety of "external sort" where you sort the array indexes vs the arrays, or else you need to create objects containing the pairs of data items, sort the objects, and then reconstruct the arrays.  (There is a useful data structure that could be defined here -- an array with N-element entries, so that "parallel" arrays could be represented with a single array.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you leave the `tableArray` unchanged, and use the `numberArray` as an *index* into the other array.

You would initialize the `numberArray` to `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1` with

```
numberArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [tableArray count]; i++) {
     [numberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i]];
}
```

When you need an item, e.g. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you access it via the index:

```
NSUInteger i = [[numberArray objectAtIndex:row] unsignedIntegerValue];
NSString *item = [tableArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

Now you need to reorder the `numberArray` only, and the changes will automatically be reflected in the table view.

*Update:* A good solution to handle the reordering of Core Data objects in a table view can be found here: [UITableView Core Data reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360938/uitableview-core-data-reordering?lq=1)

Comment: @MartinR  +1 this makes great sense, and thanks for the quick reply. I do just have one easy question:

what exactly is the "`(n-1)`" which looks like its contained in the array? Thank you !

Comment: if your tableArray has n entries, it would have n indexes. as the numbering of indexes starts with 0, you would uses indexes fro 0 to n-1. an example: if your tableArray has n = 100 hundred objects, the highest possible index would be 99 (= n-1 = 100-1)

Comment: @KurtMoyer: I have added some code how the numberArray would be initialized.

Comment: @MartinR I totally understand now how to initialize the array. The only thing that doesnt seem to make sense is where you access the object via the index. I can't call this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because in `viewWillAppear` I need to sort the `tableArray` according to the `numberArray` and then in `cellForRow`, (i posted the code for cellForRow in my question) So, my question is how can i sort the tableArray according to the saved order of the numberArray? Thank you very much, i appreciate the help!

Comment: @KurtMoyer: It seems that I don't (yet) understand your question completely. My idea was that you don't sort the `tableArray` at all, but only the `numberArray`. - Where and when are the order numbers generated? And you did not post code for `cellForRow...` in your question, perhaps that code would clarify the problem.

Comment: @MartinR Okay, i do apologize for not being clear. I basically load my data from core data, and load that data into an array, then put that data into the table View. Pretty basic stuff, but then i have to be able to sort this data, and keep it persistent which is where my problem is. I have looked up how to sort normal arrays, which also doesnt work. Because in `viewWIllAppear`, i reload all of the data. Anyways, i edited my question. If you dont mind taking a look at it, id appreciate it!

Comment: @KurtMoyer: So this is probably related to your previous question? I think you got quite a good answer for that. The idea is to store the order number *as an additional field in the Core Data object*, not in a separate NSArray, and add a sort descriptor to the fetch request. Then, if you reload the data, they will be in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MartinR. but i found the correct answer/tutorial [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360938/uitableview-core-data-reordering?lq=1) if you want to post a link to this answer in your answer, ill check mark your answer. And thank you again for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *unsortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1) hi",@"2) whats Up",@"3) this",@"4) is cool!",nil];
NSArray *guideArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2",@"4",@"3",@"1", nil];

for(int i=0; i< [guideArray count];i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j< [unsortedArray count];j++)
    {
        if([[[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:j] substringToIndex:[[guideArray objectAtIndex:i] length]] isEqualToString:[guideArray objectAtIndex:i]])
        //if([[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:j] containsObject:[guideArray objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            [unsortedArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:j withObjectAtIndex:i];
            break;                
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",unsortedArray);
```

**OR**

```
guideArray = @[@"2",@"4",@"3",@"1"];
unsortedArray = [@[@[@"1) hi"],
                   @[@"2) wats up "],
                   @[@"3) this,"],
                   @[@"4) cool"]] mutableCopy];

[unsortedArray sortUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    NSString *s1 = [o1 objectAtIndex:0];
    s1 = [s1 substringToIndex:[s1 rangeOfString:@")"].location];
    NSString *s2 = [o2 objectAtIndex:0];
    s2 = [s2 substringToIndex:[s2 rangeOfString:@")"].location];
    NSInteger idx1 = [guideArray indexOfObject:s1];
    NSInteger idx2 = [guideArray indexOfObject:s2];
    return idx1 - idx2;
}];
NSLog(@"%@",unsortedArray);
```

Try this hope this help partially.

Comment: in your second example o1 and o2 are strings, there-for sending `objectAtIndex:` will result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see a way to solve it with a predicate

```
NSArray *stringArray = @[@"hi", @"what's up?", @"this", @"is cool"];
NSArray *numberArray = @[@2, @4, @3, @1];
NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

//connect string with the numbers of there new position
[numberArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *string =stringArray[[obj integerValue]-1];
    [combinedArray addObject:@[string, obj]];
}];


NSMutableArray *orderedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[combinedArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [orderedArray addObject:obj[0]];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", orderedArray);
```

*result*

```
(
    "what's up?",
    "is cool",
    this,
    hi  
)
```